# How to use Fragments in Vuejs 2.x if using Jsx?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Given that, React has Fragments and the official github [thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7088) too doesn't offers any solution as such.

What would be the workaround for that  in Vuejs. This might help developers migrating to Vuejs from React background i.e who prefer render function styles and JSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple, if you're not doing it for the root element of the component. For example you already have a root div having multiple nodes returned from sub-render functions.

As we used to divide the render functions in React, we can do the same way here.

**Solution:**

Here is the code

```
render(h) {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.isConfirm ? this.renderF1(h) : this.renderF2(h)}
      </div>
    );
},
methods: {
    //eslint-disable-next-line
    renderF1: function(h){
        return [
            <div></div>,
            <div class='anotherDiv'></div>
        ]
    },
    //eslint-disable-next-line
    renderF2: function(h){
        return [
            <span></span>,
            <div class='secondDiv'></div>
        ]
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

**First** step is to return the multiple root node elements from `array` like this

```
return [node, node];
```

**Next**, Vue CLI will throw an error for `function h`. So from your main `render` function simply pass `h` as an argument to those other smaller render functions.

After this code should run.

***Note*** - if you have `eslint`, you just might want to add this line

`//eslint-disable-next-line`

on top of each render function to avoid compilation error.

Further - If you're coming first time to JSX land in Vuejs, I used official Babel plugin [package](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx)

So if you can try to work around with your component hierarchies in a way, you atleast have something to work on. Using array as return as a root element results in error though

For example, if we did

```
render(h) {

 return [
      <div>
        {this.isConfirm ? this.renderF1(h) : this.renderF2(h)}
      </div>
    ];
},
```

Vue errs out this

`Multiple root nodes returned from render function. Render function should return a single root node.`

Comment: You can alos write the methods as `renderF1(h){` instead of `renderF1: function(h){` as they mean the same (and that also fixes the eslint warning)

Comment: Omg. I can't believe you pointed that. I hope the concern is clear!